# How can I get adb to synthesize rapid tapping on android phone?

Tags: android, shell, scripting, adb

The command itself seems to take forever to do repetitive tasks and I was hoping to get something quicker. I have tried putting it in a loop but its still slow, the only way to get any more speed out of it is to open 4 - 5 terminal shells and run each loop independently.

Comment: Have you consider Monkeyrunner? I am not sure if it works in your context as you left that out, but it is designed to rapidly (albeit randomly) click on your screen
https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkeyrunner/index.html

Comment: Would it work on an app that I dont own and is there a good tutorial for how to use it?

Comment: See the above link for a tutorial on how to use it. I am not terribly familiar with monkeyrunner I just know the general purpose of it.